# SugarCRM How to allow a user to view the case created by himself and his assigned case

Tags: sugarcrm

I am newly working on SugarCRM CE and kindly need your help.
When our end user creates a new Case, so the Case will be assigned to another user different of the creator user.
We need that the both user, between the creator and the "assigned to", both of them  be able to see the Case.

Comment: I have done similar in my previous project. I can't give you exact code description, but will give you an idea.First set the role to that modules to all. Then on that modules edit or detail view, check that whether the current user is one of the user who created the case or to whom case is currently assigned. And using this, you can grant or restrict access to that particular record. There are many ways to achieve this, from simple to complex. I gave you a simple one. Let me know, if you still need any help.